# how to use ttf files to estimate how the browser wraps text in a fixed width div

Tags: python, fonts, python-imaging-library

I would like to estimate the height of a div element containing only text as rendered by a browser.  For example, consider this htm file:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="position:absolute; top:100pt; left:80pt; width:200pt">
      <p style="line-height:16pt; font-size:9pt; font-family:Monospace; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my attempt in python:

```
from PIL import ImageFont
import re


def getHeightOfTextBox(line_height, font_size, ttfFileName, box_width, text):
    text = text.strip()
    text = re.sub('\s+', ' ', text)
    font = ImageFont.truetype(ttfFileName, font_size)
    numLines = 1
    cursor = 0

    spaceWidth = font.getsize(' ')[0]
    afterLineBreak = False

    for word in text.split(' '):
        wordWidth = font.getsize(word)[0]
        cursor += wordWidth + (spaceWidth if afterLineBreak else 0)
        if cursor > box_width:
            print(word)
            numLines += 1
            afterLineBreak = True
            cursor = wordWidth
        else:
            afterLineBreak = False
            cursor += spaceWidth

    return numLines * line_height


text = '''
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
'''

print(getHeightOfTextBox(16, 9, "LiberationMono-Regular.ttf", 200, text))
```

Here is the output of the script:

```
adipiscing
incididunt
aliqua.
nostrud
nisi
Duis
in
fugiat
occaecat
culpa
id
192
```

which gives 12 lines in total.  Here is how the div element is rendered in my Firefox browser:

[image]

which gives 13 lines.  In this example, pillow says the width of a character is 5pts, so 0.025 of the width of the div.  Using Firefox's inspect element feature, Firefox calculates the width of a character to be 7px and the width of the div to be 266.667px, so 0.02625 the width of the div.  At this point, my best guess is that the reason for this discrepancy is that Firefox thinks the width if a character is slightly larger than pillow does.  If I change this example by using a font size of 10pts then I get agreement between my code and Firefox.

Is it possible to correct my code to accurately estimate, using the font metric file, the height of the div as rendered by a browser?  I know another option is to use a headless browser like PhantomJS in conjunction with Selenium.  But I am hoping to avoid this, as I feel it could be over-kill.

Comment: Before we get into solving creative hacks: why? What are you trying to actually do with the metrics obtained in this way? Also, given that fonts already contain this information, why not just look inside the font file for the general metrics metadata? Finally, this question is about HTML, why use external Python instead of making the page compute those values with browser-native JavaScript? (`getBoundingClientRect()` etc)

Comment: I am in a situation where I need to calculate the height of the above div element as rendered by a browser.  My question was: Is there a way to do this without using a headless browser like PhantomJS?

Comment: short answer: no. longer answer: no, even if there were, each browser renders differently (ranging from "ever so slightly" to "quite differently"). So, short of rendering the page with fiduciary markers, screenshooting it, and then doing image analysis on the screenshot, there is no way to get this information without testing all the browsers you need to target. At which point using on-page-JS is infinitely less work and more reliable.

Comment: `getBoundingClientRect()` would be going down the selenium route, which I would like to avoid if possible.  The reason this problem arose is that an OCR program I am using outputs an htm file.  I want to extract tables from the document, which entails modelling how the browser would position elements on a page relative to one another.

Comment: If you say that you do find agreement between the code and Firefox if you change your font size, isn't it just a wrong configuration of your code then? In other words: are you sure you are calling your function with the same font size as that you're using in Firefox?

Comment: Yes: when I use inspect element as above for 10pts, then I get a character width of 0.03 the width of the div for both firefox and pillow.

Comment: It sounds like wanting to not use a hammer when a hammer is the best tool for the job - is there any particularly good reason you don't want to install selenium, or phantomjs, or slimer, or any number of headless browsers for this job?

Comment: I just thought maybe it would be overkill (plus the web driver takes some time to load) and that maybe I was overlooking something.

Comment: asking the browser you need the metrics for for the metrics is not overkill, it's the only accurate way to measure. Installing a package that does what you need is more a "bare minimum" than overkill =)